# Why do I get a request for /_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I upgraded to java8 on appengine and my app seems to work fine but I noticed in the logs an error when it tries to access

/_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages

and

/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs

After searching it says that these requests have to do with endpoints. I am not using endpoints. Is there a way to prevent these requests from happening?

Could I have installed endpoint into the environment? If so, is there a way to figure that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the endpoints jars in my .classpath and lib folders. I removed them and those errors went away. I talked to an old co worker and he said he added endpoints to try something out that didn't end up working. So endpoints jars were being included but not used.

I had upgraded to java8 so that's why the 404 started happening. Where before it wouldn't 404 but find the config and find there was nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

There's a section for Endpoint in the Cloud Console, you can find it [here](https://console.google.google.com/endpoints). It should show up there.

Running the gcloud command to list all Endpoints should list them as well:

> $ gcloud endpoints services list

If you've determined you have one (*and you no longer need it*), you can delete it following [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/deleting-an-api-and-instances), but be careful not to delete any instances that are running your current code.

Comment: $ gcloud endpoints services list

ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'endpoints'. Did you mean 'domains'?

Is what I get when I run that command. Maybe my gcloud is out of date?

Comment: I think so. You can check with the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/list) `gcloud components list` which will list your current version and will tell you if there's an update available. [Updating](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) can be done with `gcloud components update`.